# Module not Found error in streamlit about tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, streamlit, modulenotfounderror

ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).

```
Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 542, in _run_script
    exec(code, module._dict_)
File "/mount/src/finalyearproject/streamlit.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
```

Reviewed the Streamlit logs for additional error messages or clues about the issue
How to fix it?

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you are running. However, I’m guessing you haven’t imported the module?